# Magento 2: Newsletter Queue Take Different Queue Start Time

Tags: magento2, configuration, newsletter, timezone, queue

I'm using Magento 2 CE Version 2.1.2

My locale is `Asia/Singapore`. When i queue my newsletter, it's taking different start time (or timezone).

If i put now, then also it's taking 8+ hours & in database `cron_schedule` table it also saves same time.

Everytime i need to run

```
php bin/magento cron:run
```

every time Or just once? Because both are dependent i think.

It always take `UTC` timezone although it set as `Asia/Singapore`

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7560

How to solve in general timezone issue, so it will work as per set on Admin Locale Timezone.

Comment: i am using 2.1.2 but the newsletter email is sending immediately but not in queue.

Comment: Hi @leo my server time is correct. But when i try to run cron job or set newsletter it takes UTC timezone.